# I am trying to show an image in a custom listview by taking a link from a firebase realtime database, but the image is not shown

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, listadapter

I’m making a program that takes data input from a realtime database, but when I try to show the image via the link and picasso, it doesn’t seem to work. The application starts, there are no crashes but the image is not displayed.

This is the code of the ListAdapter class

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
private int resourceLayout;
private Context mContext;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resourceLayout = resource;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = vi.inflate(resourceLayout, null);
    }

    Item p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        ImageView im1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemLogo);
        TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);

        if (im1 != null) {
            Picasso.get().load(p.getLogo()).fit().centerCrop().into(im1); //getLogo 
        }

        if (tt2 != null) {
            tt2.setText(p.getName() + "  -  " + p.getPrice() + " D");
        }

        if (tt3 != null) {
            tt3.setText(p.getDescription());
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

This is the design of the list adapter

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="16dp"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemLogo"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/itemDescription"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible somehow to solve this problem?

I don’t think the problem is the link but in case this is what I used in the tests : https://it.cleanpng.com/png-4816az/preview.html

Comment: You need to debug and add 2 breakpoints, 1st on line `if(im1 != null)` and second on the inside statement of this if-block. 1st breakpoint will help you to check if im1 is initialized properly, second will help you to see the value/path returned by `p.getLogo()` Try to copy and open the path in a browser to see this path really leads to the image.

Comment: Welcome Leo, I'm posting my earlier comment as an answer, please select it as the solution to your question and upvote it as well. Cheers

Comment: "it doesn’t seem to work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Is your URL correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug and add 2 breakpoints 
1st on line `if(im1 != null)` and second on the inside statement of this if-block. 
1st breakpoint will help you to check if `im1` is initialized properly, second will help you to see the value/path returned by `p.getLogo()` 
Try to copy and open the path in a browser to see this path really leads to the image.